# Change Images shown in slider

Tags: magento-1.9, slider

I'm working on a Magento site for the first time so my knowledge is very limited. I'm trying to change some of the images used in a slider from a product:
[image]

The slider is generated from the `media.phtml` file. The URL for the thumbnail images is obtained with `<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize($thumbWidth, $thumbHeight); ?>`

After some research I've found that all the images should be under `/media/catalog/product` but I can't find the image corresponding to the product because the URL obtained is a cached image and not the URL to the original image. Where are this product images stored in the directory structure under `/media/catalog/product`. Is there any way to change them through the admin panel?

Answer (score 0):

You can change any product image from magento Admin Panel

1) Login to Admin->Click on `Catalog` from top navigation->select `Manage Products`

2) Filter product by name or sku in manage product grid and click on row of the appeared product.

3) When product is open click on `Images` from left tabs.

4) If you want to add images click on `browse` button and select images that you want to upload then click on `upload` button.

5) If you want to remove images from that product just click on checkbox from column `remove` and click on `save` button from top right button sets.

Hope it will help you to update images of products.

Comment: I did that but there are no images there, I should be seeing the images that I already have on the slider :/

Comment: @Andres Check top left of admin panel. There is a store scope change option. It is possible the images are loaded at store level, so you need to change the scope.

Comment: @ProxiBlue I couldn't find the option but I think I'm already on the store view http://imgur.com/a/ByTsz

Comment: @Andres is provided screen shot is the same product image tab in question.

Comment: @ProxiBlue yes, same product

Comment: I am sure you have multi store. Open product and see my screen shot and try to change every value and from that dropdown and check image tab. http://amanweb.in/stackexchange/scr.jpg